# How do you Format and Concatenate an Invoice or Bank Statement with Different Ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an invoice from a service provider that I need to format so I can use the data in Excel.  But, the formatting is not consistent.

There are three (3) columns:

1. ID
2. Description
3. Amount

Many ID#s on the invoice have a one line (row) description.

But just as many have 2-11 lines (rows) of description.

The ID# is only listed once with each set of description lines.

Up to this point, I have used Excel Formulas.  But, all my formulas is making things go very slow.

`VBA` would be way faster.

What I have done is created an index system looking for new ID#s.

Then I have created a cascading concatenate formula based on the given index system.

The amount has been easy to pull out using a `LEFT` formula, since the amount lists USD.

I then have a second sheet that does a `VLOOKUP` off of the first sheet to pull the ID's, final concatenated descriptions, and Amounts.

Our last invoice had 17,427 lines of data with only 1,717 ID#s.

Here is an example of what I am working with:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: What Excel version do you have? you could tackle this with Power Query

Comment: What's your question exactly? If it is "How do I do this in VBA?" then that is too broad of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the possible solutions below:

```
'assume that Id in column `A`, Description in column `B`, Amount in `C` and header in row 1
Sub somecode()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim lastRow&: lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim idColumn As Range: Set idColumn = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim cl As Range, keyID, valueDescription$, valueAmount$

    For Each cl In idColumn
        If cl.Value <> "" And Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            dic.Add cl.Value, sh.Cells(cl.Row, "B").Value & "|" & sh.Cells(cl.Row, "C").Value
            keyID = cl.Value
            valueDescription = sh.Cells(cl.Row, "B").Value
            valueAmount = sh.Cells(cl.Row, "C").Value
        ElseIf cl.Value = "" Then
            valueDescription = valueDescription & " " & sh.Cells(cl.Row, "B").Value
            dic(keyID) = valueDescription & "|" & valueAmount
        End If
    Next cl

    Set sh = wb.Sheets.Add: sh.Name = "Result " & Date & " " & Replace(Time(), ":", "-")

    Dim dkey, xRow&: xRow = 1

    For Each dkey In dic

        sh.Cells(xRow, "A").Value = dkey
        sh.Cells(xRow, "B").Value = Split(dic(dkey), "|")(0)
        sh.Cells(xRow, "C").Value = Split(dic(dkey), "|")(1)

        xRow = xRow + 1

    Next dkey

    sh.Columns("A:C").AutoFit

End Sub
```

test:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I had to adjust the naming of the new sheet.  But, other than that, it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code for you to do this job. Please install it in a standard code module. That is one that you have to insert. None of the existing is suitable.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                        ' Worksheet setup (set values as required)
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2
    NwsNumColumns = 8           ' total number of columns in the sheet
    NwsID = 1                   ' Columns: 1 = column A
    NwsDesc                     '          undefined = previous + 1
    NwsAmt = 5                  '          5 = column E
End Enum

Sub MergeRows()
    ' Variatus @STO 24 Jan 2020

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RowArr As Variant
    Dim Desc As String, Amt As Double
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    ' define workbook and worksheet as required
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook                     ' this need not be ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Invoice")           ' change as appropriate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Ws
        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsDesc).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = R To NwsFirstDataRow Step -1
            If (R Mod 25) = 3 Then 'NwsFirstDataRow Then
                Application.StatusBar = "Another " & R & " rows to process."
            End If

            Tmp = Trim(.Cells(R, NwsID).Value)
            If Len(Tmp) Then
                Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, NwsNumColumns))
                RowArr = Rng.Value
                RowArr(1, NwsAmt) = TextToAmount(RowArr(1, NwsAmt))
                If Len(Desc) Then
                    ' if you want a comma instead of a line break
                    ' replace Chr(10) with "," in the next line:-
                    RowArr(1, NwsDesc) = RowArr(1, NwsDesc) & Chr(10) & Desc
                    RowArr(1, NwsAmt) = RowArr(1, NwsAmt) + Amt
                    Desc = ""
                    Amt = 0
                End If

                With Rng
                    .Value = RowArr
                    .Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                    .Cells(NwsAmt).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
                End With
                .Rows(R).AutoFit
            Else
                Tmp = Trim(.Cells(R, NwsDesc).Value)
                If Len(Desc) Then Desc = Chr(10) & Desc
                Desc = Tmp & Desc
                Tmp = TextToAmount(.Cells(R, NwsAmt).Value)
                If Tmp Then Amt = Amt + Tmp
                .Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .StatusBar = "Done"
    End With
End Sub

Private Function TextToAmount(ByVal Amt As Variant) As Double

    Dim Tmp As Variant

    Tmp = Trim(Amt)
    If Len(Tmp) Then Tmp = Mid(Tmp, InStr(Tmp, "$") + 1)
    TextToAmount = Val(Tmp)
End Function
```

Before you can run it you need to set the enumerations at the top to tell the code where your data and columns are. Toward the same end, please set the variables for workbook (Wb) and worksheet (Ws) in the procedure itself.

Note that the code adds the price, if any, in the rows that are deleted to the amount set against the remaining item.

Finally, you will see that I programmed the different rows to become lines in a single cell. That isn't what you asked for. If you want the items separate by commas look for the remark in the code where you can change this.